# What is the "official" way to use Selenium 2 (Selenium WebDriver) with Maven?

Tags: maven-2, selenium-webdriver

I'm just trying to make the basic Selenium2Example work with Firefox 4 using Maven to get the Selenium jars :

```
public class Selenium2Example  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
        // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
        // not the implementation.
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        // And now use this to visit Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        // Find the text input element by its name
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

        // Enter something to search for
        element.sendKeys("Cheese!");

        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
        element.submit();

        // Check the title of the page
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

        //Close the browser
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

If I go there : http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/UsingWebDriver, it says I should try a dependency like this :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium</artifactId>
    <version>2.0b3</version>
</dependency>
```

but the latest jars can be found in no repositories, the last version which works (with all dependencies found) is "2.0a4" (2.0a5 to 2.0a7 and 2.0b1 to 2.0b3 have missing main jars or missing dependencies), and this "2.04" version doesn't have the right classes to make the example work.

If I go there : http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#chapter03-reference, it says I should use this dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.webdriver</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdriver-firefox</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.7376</version>
</dependency>
```

It makes the example compile, but this release hasn't been updated since october 2009, and it doesn't run with Firefox 4 (see http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/webdriver/webdriver-firefox/)

If I go there http://seleniumhq.org/download/maven.html, it says I should try something like :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
</dependency>
```

But the 2.0b3 version doesn't work either (missing dependencies). Here is the error message :

```
23/05/11 22:09:07 CEST: Build errors for first-webdriver-test; org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project first-webdriver-test: Unable to get dependency information for org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.0.1: Failed to process POM for org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.0.1: Non-resolvable parent POM org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcomponents-core:4.0.1 for org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.0.1: Failed to resolve POM for org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcomponents-core:4.0.1 due to Missing:
----------
1) org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcomponents-core:pom:4.0.1
----------
1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact: 
  org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcomponents-core:pom:4.0.1

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false)
```

I don't know the meaning of this error, since I can find the requested pom here : http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-core/4.0.1/httpcomponents-core-4.0.1.pom

So the only way I can make the example work for now, is manually downloading the 2.0b3 jars.

Does anybody succeed in making it work with Maven ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this is working (with Maven 2.2.1):

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
     <artifactId>selenium</artifactId>
     <version>2.0b3</version>
     <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>
```

Notice this line: `<type>pom</type>`

Also, I had to add the dependency on the junit library to get it to pass some surefire exceptions, but you might not need this.

Comment: You're totally right, it works ! I thought I had already tried to add "pom". I've added a comment to the official wiki (http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/UsingWebDriver)

Comment: Wrong information.  You are describing how to pull out only one part of the selenium stack and as a result you are not pulling down the dependancies.  This is not the "Official" way to do it.

Comment: I never claimed this to be the "official" way to do it. I just said it worked for me.

Comment: "You are describing how to pull out only one part of the selenium stack" Sorry Ardesco, but you're wrong, because the "selenium" pom artifact depends on selenium-remote-control and selenium-server, so it is necessary more complete than "selenium-remote-control" only (see http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium/2.0b3/selenium-2.0b3.pom).

Comment: *sigh* read through the selenium dev mailing list thread I supplied.  As stated in my answer they switched it from selenium to selenium-remote-control.  It broke everybody's POM dependancy when they did it.  Keep using this by all means but it's wrong.

Comment: I've read it all man... It's not contradictory with using the dependency above. Maybe you should try yourself, and you will see your project still work.

Answer (score 2):

Since RC2, you just need:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium</artifactId>
            <version>2.0rc2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

With RC3 you need:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.0rc3</version>
</dependency>
```

to include all the jar

Answer (score -1):

For me, this works:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>4.8.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.29.1</version>
</dependency> 

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.29.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency> 
    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.01</version>               
</dependency>
```